# Storing data in pre-defined XML files

Tags: android, xml

I'm trying to figure out how to store data in pre-defined xml files (the files should be part of the project).
I've tried to several methods but non worked.
Instead of asking what is wrong with what I'm doing, I rather ask what is a good known working method to do that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of tutorials about parsing xml. Try those by IBM. Just place your xml in/assets and parse it. But I believe newest api has even more convinient way to do it. Refer to dev guide. As fo xml itself just follow common standarts.

Comment: I Think I missed the 'assets' part, didn't think of using it and I think it should solve the problems I've met. I'll try that...10x

Answer (score 1):

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/